# show Image over image flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Need to show image above other image outside the widget margin.

[image: Requried output]

I tried using stack, but it not coming outside.

```
Stack(children: <Widget>[
  Container(child: Image.asset('assets/discover.png')),
  Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(child: Text(''), flex: 9),
      Expanded(
        child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(80.0),
            child: Image.asset('assets/user.jpg')),
        flex: 6,
      ),
      Expanded(child: Text(''), flex: 9)
    ],
  ),
]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below source code works for your scenario. You have to give top padding for the image's container and make the entire stack's alignment as topCenter.

Additional things:

1. Consider giving height and width for the circled image.
2. Keep the big image widget in AspectRatio widget to occupy the full width of its parent widget and give fit property as well for showing entire image in the right fit.

.

```
Stack(
    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
    children: <Widget>[
        Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
            child: AspectRatio(aspectRatio: 1, child: Image.asset('assets/discover.png', fit: BoxFit.cover),),
        ),
        ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
            child: Image.asset('assets/user.jpg', height: 80, width: 80),
        ),
    ],
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Stack(children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0),
          child: Image.network(
              'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/06/19/21/24/the-road-815297__340.jpg'),
        ),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(child: Text(''), flex: 9),
            Expanded(
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(80.0),
                child: Image.asset('assets/ic_profile.png'),
              ),
              flex: 6,
            ),
            Expanded(child: Text(''), flex: 9)
          ],
        )
      ]),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Flutter demo'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 10, 5, 10),
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
              child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                  child: Image.network(
                      'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQGLanNnFsLi3QnQFdh-k-mkwG6yrEEXhorSoElObizTnP0_8rR')),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              child: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 30.0,
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                    'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSIekuJOwtOWtZl9QX3t46Yz_7RCZ4Kpebnugsst2OFfNl-SGjf'),
                backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
              ),
            )
          ]),
        ));
```

[image: Screenshot]